# Not being able to connect IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

So here's a problem I have been stuck at for 2 hours now! 
I have a Table View Controller with static cell table View. 
In one of the static table View Cells I have placed a tableView with dynamic cells. I have created a custom class for that tableViewCell. The problem is that I cannot connect the dynamic cell tableView to my custom class no matter what I do. 
Anybody faced this similar issue? Please share some insight on how to resolve this.

The following line  used to reuse my custom tableView cell in the tableViewController throws an error **Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCellTVC") as! MyCustomTableViewCell
```

Comment: did you register class(or nib) for your `MyCustomTableViewCell` in the tableView?

Comment: Yes I did @fiks

Comment: @Watson please share the register code

Comment: @Watson please link  again .Main.Storyboard about  IBOutlet reference in ViewController file,

Comment: Something is not quite clear... in the line that crash is `tableView` referring to the static table view or the dynamic one that's inside the cell?

Comment: Hi all!  Sorry I couldn't reply earlier. @Marc-AlexandreBérubé the line is referring to a static tableView that is trying to dequeue a custom tableViewCell(which has dynamic tableView)

Comment: But usually static tableView shouldn't need to be dequeued (as they are static)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer to the problem and here is what I did

**dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)** works for dynamic tableView cells. As my main tableView was static, **dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)** was returning **nil** everytime it ran. So instead , I did this

```
let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as? MyCustomTableViewCell
```

I had already made the UI for my custom cell in the tableView storyboard. Use of identifier for tableViewCells is trivial. The tableView already knows the position of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

**dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)** can and will return nil while building the initial pool of cells.

If you don't want to check for nil and get a cell at all times use [tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview)

BTW: I may be wrong, but adding a table inside a table is frowned upon :)